# Why use DER encoding for signatures?

Tags: signature, ecdsa

A signature in secp256k1 is two 32 byte numbers. DER encoding a signature adds about 6-7 bytes.  It also needlessly complicates things (is DER encoding used anywhere else?).  In a transaction format that seems to try to squeeze every byte out, this is very strange to me.  Why not just use a 64 byte string to represent sigs instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess is that Satoshi did not know about the internals of ECDSA signatures, and simply used what OpenSSL gave him.

If it didn't require a hard forking change (requiring every wallet and verifying node on the network to upgrade), we'd have changed it long ago.